# Swift NSString function syntax usage

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I have a basic question about swift function calling syntax. I have read documentation but not able to figure it out. So decided to put a query over here.

A piece of code i wrote

```
    var string1 = NSString().stringByAppendingString("First string")
    var string2 = NSString.stringByAppendingString("Second string")

    println(string1)
    println(string2)
```

Both string have same function calling but return type is different. And only difference here is `()`. I got out put like

> First string
>
> (Function)

Question is why its not giving a warning/error. Is it that `var string2` holds method body of `stringByAppendingString`? Whats going on, New swift developer like me can easily make a this type of typo mistake and not able to figure out.

Can you please explain why its not return value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because swift methods are curried functions (you can find detailed explanation in [Ole Begemann's post](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)).

So what you actually got in the following line:

```
var string2 = NSString.stringByAppendingString("Second string")
```

is a function that takes a string as parameter and returns the result of

```
"Second string".stringByAppendingString(parameter)
```

You can check that by calling string2 as an ordinary function:

```
string2("123")
// Prints: "Second string123"
```